# delete everything from List<string> with specific string

Tags: c#, linq

i have:

```
List<string> MyFiles
```

i need to delete everything from this list that has a specific string inside of it

for example if the list was:

```
alex1
alex123
alex234
alex345
```

and i would like to delete every element in this list that has the string "1" in it?

Comment: Are you sure linq-to-sql is appropriate? Barring further info, this is an in-memory collection.

Comment: it can be done any way i dont care

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MyFiles.RemoveAll(s => s.Contains("1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

C#

`MyFiles.RemoveAll((string s) => s.Contains("1"))`

I code in VB.NET:

`MyFiles.RemoveAll(Function(s As String) s.Contains("1"))`

Comment: Sorry for the seemingly duplicate answer, there were no answers when I clicked the link.  I had to go and convert the VB to C#, came back, posted, and there was the answer already.